# Restart current iteration in 'for' loop java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop that asks the user to input a number and then does something with it 10 times

I want a check built in that, if the user enters a non accepted input, the loop should restart its current iteration

For example if the user enters something wrong in round 3, round 3 should be restarted.

How do i do that? is there something like a REDO statement in java?

Comment: Ok, what you have tried?

Comment: Do you go to the same school as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066736)?

Comment: Use a `do-while` loop, not a `for` loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

something like this ?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   if(input wrong){
     i=i-1;
   }

}
```

Comment: that is what i did, just wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: @Killerpixler yes, use a `do-while` loop instead of decreasing the `i` value.

Comment: I think that changing the value of a loop control variable inside the loop tends to be confusing. Simple enough in this case, but in a large loop it might be non-obvious what is going on.  I prefer the answer posted by @Mik378: use an inner loop to re-prompt for input until valid input is received.

Comment: @DaveCosta that is absolutely true for large loops. but dont you think its kinda expensive to have an nested loop ??

Comment: @chaitanya10 That doesn't decrease performance at all to have this kind of inner loop.

Comment: I have implemented the solution using a do-while, better for readabilty and understanding.

Answer (score 10):

You have a couple of choices here.

**Continue**
The *continue* statement in Java tells a loop to go back to its starting point. If you're using a for loop, however, this will continue on to the next iteration which is probably not what you want, so this works better with a while loop implementation:

```
int successfulTries = 0;
while(successfulTries < 10)
{
    String s = getUserInput();
    if(isInvalid(s))
        continue;

    successfulTries++;
}
```

**Decrement**
This approach seems ugly to me, but if you want to accomplish your task using a for loop, you can instead just decrement the counter in your for loop (essentially, 'redo') when you detect bad input.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    String s = getUserInput();
    if(isInvalid(s))
    {
        i--;
        continue;
    }
}
```

I recommend you use a while loop.

Answer (score 5):

Prefer avoiding to reassign the `i` variable, this may lead to confusion.

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      String command = null;
      do{
        command = takeCommandFromInput();
      } while(isNotValid(command));
      process(command);
  }
```