# How to make a loop run until the console prints a certain statement within that loop?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to achieve a certain result or output before terminating the loop.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class learnjava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How old are you?");

        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Do you prefer cats or dogs?");

        String animal = scanner.nextLine();

        if (age > 10 || animal.equals("cats")) 
        {System.out.println("welcome!");}
        else {System.out.println("No access");}

    scanner.close();
        }   

}
```

Ideally I want to create a loop that makes my code run until system prints out welcome, so that I can avoid restarting the program. I want to provide the user another chance at inputting right answers once the first input fails without running again, hence the console should ask again *"how old are you?"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart current iteration in 'for' loop java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089765/restart-current-iteration-in-for-loop-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `do while` loop for this use case. The actual validation logic can be put within the loop and the loop will be terminated only if the condition is invalid.

So in you case, the loop will check the condition `age < 10 || !animal.equals("cat")`. So the loop will run till the age exceeds 10 or the animal is "cat". As this is an exit check loop, it will exit only after printing **"Welcome"** to the console.

The code is as follows,

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String animal;
        int age;

        do{
          System.out.println("How old are you?");

          age = scanner.nextInt();
          scanner.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Do you prefer cats or dogs?");

          animal = scanner.nextLine();

          if (age > 10 || animal.equals("cats")) 
          {
            System.out.println("welcome!");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("No access");
          }
        }while(age < 10 || !animal.equals("cat"));

        scanner.close();
      }   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the logic in a while loop with a boolean variable to indicate the `isFinished` status:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class learnjava {

    private static final String WELCOME = "welcome!";
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED_TRY_AGAIN = "No access";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean isFinished = false;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!isFinished) {

            System.out.println("How old are you?");
            int age = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Do you prefer cats or dogs?");
            String animal = scanner.nextLine();

            if (age > 10 || animal.equals("cats")) {
                System.out.println(WELCOME);
                isFinished = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println(ACCESS_DENIED_TRY_AGAIN);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use loops in java for repeated task. **while loop** is one of them

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            if (askUser(scanner)) {
                System.out.println("welcome!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No access");
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    private static boolean askUser(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("How old are you?");

        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Do you prefer cats or dogs?");

        String animal = scanner.nextLine();

        return (age > 10 || animal.equals("cats"));

    }
```